# Passing variables to another page using $_GET not working

Tags: php, html, get

`$_GET` is not working when passing variables from one page to another page.

Title - ID - Embed are all showing in the URL on page two so I don't think the problem is on page 1 being that is appears to be passing the variables.

The `$_GET['embed']` is working on page 2 but not the `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['title']`

Page 1:

```
$title = $row['title'];;
$id = $row['id'];;
$linkurl = $row['embed'];;
$src1 = $row['thumbs1'];; 
echo '<a href="show/video_show.php?title='.$title.'&id='.$id.'&embed='.$linkurl.'"><img height="160" width="260"  style="border:none;" src="'. $src1 .'" /></a>';
```

Page 2:

```
Title: <? echo $_GET['title']; ?>  
<iframe src="<?php echo $_GET['embed'];?>"allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" scrolling="no" width="770" height="440"></iframe>
<p>Video Number: <? echo $_GET['id'];?>
 <!-- embed is working -->
```

Comment: What you see in your URL? Is your `$row` array not empty? isn't `<?` be `<?php`?

Comment: try changing your tags to `<?php` instead os `<?`

Comment: @Charles White, please check my answer. I hope it solves your issue.

Comment: missing `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue in your PAGE 2 file :

Replace `<?` with `<?php`

```
Title: <?php echo $_GET['title']; ?>  // changed
<iframe src="<?php echo $_GET['embed'];?>"allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" scrolling="no" width="770" height="440"></iframe>
<p>Video Number: <?php echo $_GET['id'];?> //changed
 <!-- embed is working -->
```

Comment: Worked like a charm - how I didn't catch that after hours of trying to figure out the problem is beyond me. Thanks a million!

Comment: Feel free to up-vote/accept if it helped anyhow or you found it useful. @CharlesWhite

Comment: It's my first time to ask a question on the site and I have been searching how to vote. I'll find it. :)

Comment: @CharlesWhite, I hope this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) helps you and also you'll earn a badge by going through this link